# Scheduling tasks with 'schtasks' without admin privileges C#

Tags: c#, process, scheduled-tasks, command-line-arguments

I am trying to schedule the tasks from my application using `schtasks` instead of using the Windows Task Scheduler COM/managed API.
Creating a task here is easier by using this on command line `schtasks /Create /tn "MyApp" /tr c:\myapp.exe /sc onlogon` but I opened the command line as an administrator to get the task created (otherwise I get access denied)

From my application, to create the task I use

```
string args = @"/Create /tn MyApp /tr c:\myapp.exe /sc onlogon";
Process.Start("schtasks", args);
```

However, the task gets created only if I run my application as an administrator. I need to avoid this, so that any user can create the task without the hassle of running the app as admin. Any suggestions on how ca this be done?

Comment: What exactly are you up to? Do you mean the task gets created or the task runs when you run as administrator?

Comment: @Chibueze Opata: No, the task does is not even created.

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to avoid admin privileges? It looks suspicious.. the workaround is quite far-fetched.. and not advisable

Comment: @Chibueze Opata: Because the app is kind of running in kind of running for a demo, and has to be work automatically without any user interruption/input

Comment: demo to run continuously on people's PC whenever they logon without even a single consent of theirs?

Comment: Why should that require user interruption each time in an exhibition booth PC which is mounted just for exposition purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a sort of RunAs that allow to run a process with a specified user :

```
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("schtasks");
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.UserName = "Username";
    psi.Password = "password";

    Process.Start(psi);
```

The Process class through ProcessStartInfo provides a mechanism which allows you to specify the user context that the new process should run under, so you can specify the user in which you want to run the command even if the user that start the program is different. In your case you can specify Administrator credentials to the ProcessStartInfo without having to run the program with an Administrator user ...

Comment: So, when I distribute my application, what's the username and password in that case? ;-/ Taking input from the user would be very strange, since in a totally unrelated application, a user might not even give the credentials.

Comment: What would happen on PC's where the user has not configured his/her password?

Comment: I don't know, there are different ways of handling the situation, it depends on the context ...

Comment: Personally, I don't have a password on my home machine. So, I am not sure about the thing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

> Why should that require user interruption each time in an exhibition
>   booth PC which is mounted just for exposition purpose?

If you want a hidden program that will run on a PC whenever it is booted, and your task is not harmful, you can add it to the following registry key:

> HKCU\Software\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

programmatically. I can provide code if needed.

Comment: I tried this approach already, but that does not solve the purpose of  automatically starting the application at 6 am, which can be done by Task Scheduler. :-/

Comment: Sorry, I'm just having problems seeing things the way you see it. Your explanations always seem shrouded... Maybe http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ could help you. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Contents of TextBox:  "SCHTASKS.exe /Create /ST 06:30 /SC DAILY /TN report /TR notepad.exe"

I was able to use Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo);

```
ProcessStartInfo psinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

psinfo.Filename = "powershell.exe";
psinfo.Args = textbox1.text;

Process.Start(psinfo);
```

**Of course, this will only work on machines that have powershell installed, using cmd.exe failed to create the scheduled task...